# Pass params for getopt from a script that does not use getopt

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, getopts

I have a script (let’s call it `scriptC`) that uses `getopt` to parse short and long options and works fine.

This script is being called like this:
`scriptA` runs `scriptB` which calls `scriptC` with the proper parameters.

Question: Is it possible to pass the same parameters as arguments to `scriptA` and then those be passed over eventually to `scriptC`?
The scripts are called like:
`scriptB "$@"` and in `scriptB` it eventually does `scriptC —param1 —param2`

Comment: `getopt(1)` is outdated since 1986, better use the standardized `getopts(1).`

Comment: @schily:What do you mean standardized. E.g. I think Mac does not support it and I don't know if all Linux distros do

Comment: Apple definitely does - if not, tell them to withdraw their POSIX certification. Linux distros of course support it. Please note that getopt(1) has been made obsolete in 1986 because the interface definition makes it mainly unusable. getopts(1) is built into all shells (except csh) and maintains state variables as shell variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `scriptA` calls `scriptB` like

```
scriptB "$@"
```

then the command line arguments that were used for invoking `scriptA` will be passed to `scriptB` provided that these have not been altered before the call.

Likewise for the call from `scriptB` to `scriptC`.

As long as `scriptA` and `scriptB` does not try to interpret, change or otherwise mutate the contents of `$@` (or the individual positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.), the command line arguments will be passed on to `scriptC` for it to parse with `getopt`.

---

Example using functions instead of scripts (it works the same way):

```
#!/bin/sh

scriptC () {
    printf 'Arg: %s\n' "$@"
}

scriptB () {
    scriptC "$@"
}

scriptA () {
    scriptB "$@"
}

scriptA -param1 -param2
```

This will produce the output

```
Arg: -param1
Arg: -param2
```

Doing the call as

```
scriptA "hello world" --param1 /etc/passwd --param2
```

will produce

```
Arg: hello world
Arg: --param1
Arg: /etc/passwd
Arg: --param2
```

That is, the parameters will be passed on to `scriptC` without modification. It is then left to `scriptC` to interpret the parameters using `getopt`, `getopts` or by some other means.

Comment: what about `--param1`?

Comment: @Jim What about `--param1`?  _Anything_ you passed on the command line will be forwarded if you do it like this.  `--param`, `"hello world"` or whatever was on the original command line. The point is that the intermediate scripts don't try to interpret what's on the command line, they just pass it on.